# Complexity of a simple algorithm to find a prime number

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, primes, asymptotic-complexity

I want know if the asymptotic complexity of this simple algorithm to find a prime number is O(n):

```
PrimeNumber(n)
Int i;
If (n%2=0) then { return "not prime"; }
Else {
  For(i=3;i<(√n)+1;i=i+2;){
    If (n%i=0) then {return "not prime";}
  }     
}
return "prime";
```

Answer (score 4):

Time complexity is `O(sqrt(n))`, since the loop iterates itself `(sqrt(n)+1-3)/2` times, which is in `O(sqrt(n))`.

Note that since `O(sqrt(n))` is a *subset* of `O(n)`, it is also correct to say it is `O(n)` - but that bound is not tight.

Comment: That's the complexity when the argument `n` is indeed prime. The complexity when `n` is composite requires some number theoretic analysis.

Comment: @JamesKPolk This is worst case complexity.